# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.inrev.segmentation.bean.IRUserSegment

Tags: java, arraylist, javabeans

Hi i have an `ArrayList` which generic type is Bean class type. When I try to get data from the `ArrayList` I am getting an Exception.

Here is the code:

```
ArrayList<IRUserSegment> segments = (ArrayList<IRUserSegment>) userSegmentDAO.getDateWiseCount(org.getOrgId());
System.out.println("List size"+segments.size());
//  IRUserSegment itr=segments.get(1);//getting Iterator from arraylist to traverse elements  
for (int i = 0; i < segments.size(); i++) {
    IRUserSegment value = segments.get(i);
    System.out.println("Element: " + value.getCount());
}
```

**DAO CODE**
    public  List getDateWiseCount(Integer orgId) {

```
        IRUserSegment usersegment = null;

        try
        {

            q.append("SELECT count(*) as cnt, date(updatedOn) as updatedOnDate FROM t_user_segment WHERE updatedOn >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 15 DAY) group by updatedOnDate;");
            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(q.toString());
             segmentList = (List<IRUserSegment>) query.list();

            //ArrayList<IRUserSegment> details=(ArrayList<IRUserSegment>) 
            if (segmentList != null && segmentList.size() > 0)
            {
                List<Object[]> result = query.list();

                for (Object[] object : result)
                {
                    System.out.println("Count"+object[0].toString()+"date"+object[1].toString());
                }

                return segmentList;
            }

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error("", e);
        }
        return segmentList;

    }
```

Comment: Please show the exception stacktrace, and which line throws it. My guess is `userSegmentDAO.getDateWiseCount()` returns a `List` of things that aren't `IRUserSegment`.

Comment: That's a casting error ,the function return type can't be casted to `(ArrayList<IRUserSegment>)` , please put your function `getDateWiseCount` code

Comment: you cannot cast any return type from userSegmentDAO.getDateWiseCount(org.getOrgId()) to Arraylist,If possible please share the code for userSegmentDAO.getDateWiseCount()

Comment: Dark Army : i have shared code  there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using like this.

```
List segments = userSegmentDAO.getDateWiseCount(org.getOrgId());
System.out.println("List size"+segments.size());
//  IRUserSegment itr=segments.get(1);//getting Iterator from arraylist to traverse elements  
for (int i = 0; i < segments.size(); i++) {
    IRUserSegment value = (IRUserSegment)segments.get(i);
    System.out.println("Element: " + value.getCount());
}
```

or you modify your method as

```
public List<IRUserSegment> getDateWiseCount(Integer orgId) {}
```

instead of

```
public List getDateWiseCount(Integer orgId) {}
```